# Android Xamarin where is extra parameter coming from in UpdateModel method

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Hoping for someone to help me figure out what's going on. I'm debugging an Android Xamarin application using the Android Emulator, Visual Studio, and Chrome's Remote Device debugging tools.

Code seems very simple - there's a line to wire up my UpdateModel method:

```
this.Web.RegisterCallback("updateModel", UpdateModel);
```

an UpdateModel method with this signature:

```
private void UpdateModel(string content)
```

and there's a select list with options. I know this is rendering right because I am looking at it in Elements tab in the Chrome debugger:

```
<select class="abc" name="mySelect">
   <option value></option>
   <option value="3">MyFirstItem</option> 
   <option value="6">MySecondItem</option>
   . . . 
</select>
```

When the UpdateModel method is called, specifically just for this particular select list, it sends in two values, so if I pick MySecondItem, then the value of the content variable received by UpdateModel is as follows:

```
mySelect=6&mySelect=''
```

I can't figure out where the empty value is coming from since it seems to me like this is all the code that's relevant. Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

There was another hidden input getting rendered on the form with the same name. That control was sending the second input.